Is there a way of running preLaunchTask in any way on AndroidStudio
I'm currently working on a Flutter project and I tend to use VSCode, this is my configuration:
Json:
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "UAT",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "program": "lib/main.dart",
            "preLaunchTask": "UAT",
            "args": [
                "--target",
                "lib/main.dart",
                "--dart-define-from-file=env.json",
            ],
        }
    ]
}

Which basically runs a task that has this command:
Json:
"command": "setup.sh uat",

Thing is that I'm trying to find a way for my colleges using AndroidStudio to get a similar experience by using the runConfigurations in AndroidStudio
I have tried adding external tools, and it worked just fine... But you cannot add them to git because it's stored locally, so it refers to a tool u don't have
I also thought about adding it to build.gradle, but I do not manage to get it working
Is there any advice u guys could give me?
Thanks! :)

I've created a script that takes the ".vscode/launch.json" and based on it (and the preLaunchTask it might have) it generates both ".idea/runConfigurations/[config].xml's" and some scripts, that get's added to my Makefile (if you use command line tool or want to run it from pipelines)

# Generate run configurations from launch.json
# Usage: ./generate.sh

# Colors
RESET='\033[0m'
SUCCESS='\033[0;32m'
WARN='\033[0;33m'
ERROR='\033[0;31m'

# Install jq if not installed
if ! command -v jq &>/dev/null; then
    echo -e "${WARN}jq not found, installing...${RESET}"

    # Try to install using brew
    if command -v brew &>/dev/null; then
        brew install jq
    else
        echo -e "${ERROR}brew not found, please install jq manually${RESET}"
        exit 1
    fi
fi

# Launch.json file
LAUNCH_JSON_FILE=".vscode/launch.json"
# Run configurations directory
RUN_CONFIGURATIONS_DIR=".idea/runConfigurations"
# Scripts directory
SCRIPTS_DIR="scripts/configs"
# Tasks.json file
TASKS_JSON_FILE=".vscode/tasks.json"
# Android Studio build.gradle file
ANDROID_GRADLE_FILE="android/scripts/build.gradle"
# Android settings.gradle file
ANDROID_SETTINGS_GRADLE="android/settings.gradle"
# Makefile path
MAKEFILE="Makefile"

# Check if launch.json file exists
if [ ! -f "$LAUNCH_JSON_FILE" ]; then
    echo -e "${ERROR}$LAUNCH_JSON_FILE not found: ${RESET}"
    exit 1
fi

# Check if tasks.json file exists
if [ ! -f "$TASKS_JSON_FILE" ]; then
    echo -e "${WARN}$TASKS_JSON_FILE not found, preLaunchTasks will be ignored${RESET}"
fi

# Check if run configurations directory exists, if it does, cleanup, if not, create it
if [ ! -d "$RUN_CONFIGURATIONS_DIR" ]; then
    echo -e "${WARN}$RUN_CONFIGURATIONS_DIR not found${RESET}"
    echo -e "Creating run configurations directory..."
    mkdir -p $RUN_CONFIGURATIONS_DIR
else
    echo -e "Cleaning up run configurations directory..."
    rm -rf $RUN_CONFIGURATIONS_DIR/*
fi

# Check if scripts directory exists, if not, create it
if [ ! -d "$SCRIPTS_DIR" ]; then
    echo -e "${WARN}$SCRIPTS_DIR not found${RESET}"
    echo -e "Creating scripts directory..."
    mkdir -p $SCRIPTS_DIR
else
    echo -e "Cleaning up scripts directory..."
    rm -rf $SCRIPTS_DIR/*
fi

# Ensure the directory for build.gradle exists
mkdir -p $(dirname $ANDROID_GRADLE_FILE)

# Initialize build.gradle content
echo "" >$ANDROID_GRADLE_FILE

# Function to get task command
get_task_command() {
    local task_label=$1
    jq -r ".tasks[] | select(.label == \"$task_label\") | .command" $TASKS_JSON_FILE
}

# Function to clean empty lines at the end of a file
clean_empty_lines() {
    local file=$1
    # Remove empty lines at the end of the file
    sed -i '' -e :a -e '/^\n*$/{$d;N;ba' -e '}' "$file"
    # Add a newline at the end of the file
    echo >>"$file"
}

# Function to update Makefile
update_makefile() {
    local environments=""
    local makefile_content=""

    # Extract unique environment names from configurations
    while read -r CONFIGURATION; do
        ENV_NAME=$(echo $CONFIGURATION | jq -r '.name' | cut -d ' ' -f1)
        if [[ ! $environments =~ $ENV_NAME ]]; then
            environments+="$ENV_NAME "
        fi
    done <<<"$CONFIGURATIONS"

    # Generate Makefile content
    makefile_content=$(
        cat <<EOF
# Environment targets | ⚠️ DO NOT ADD ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE
.PHONY: $(echo $environments | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
$(for env in $environments; do
            env_lower=$(echo $env | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
            echo "$env_lower: ## Build/Run for $env environment. Use 'make $env_lower [args=\"build|run [additional args]\"]'"
        done)
$(echo $environments | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'):
    @if [ -z "\$(args)" ]; then \\
        ./scripts/configs/\$(shell printf '%s' "\$@" | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]').sh run; \\
    else \\
        ./scripts/configs/\$(shell printf '%s' "\$@" | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]').sh \$(args); \\
    fi
EOF
    )

    # Update Makefile
    if [ -f "$MAKEFILE" ]; then
        # Remove existing environment targets section
        sed -i '' '/^# Environment targets | ⚠️ DO NOT ADD ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE/,/^$/d' "$MAKEFILE"

        # Append new environment targets
        echo "$makefile_content" >>"$MAKEFILE"

        echo -e "${SUCCESS}Updated Makefile with new environment targets${RESET}"
    else
        echo -e "${WARN}Makefile not found. Creating a new one with environment targets${RESET}"
        echo "$makefile_content" >"$MAKEFILE"
    fi
}

# Get configurations from launch.json
CONFIGURATIONS=$(jq -c '.configurations[]' $LAUNCH_JSON_FILE)

echo "Generating run configurations..."

HAS_PRE_LAUNCH_TASKS=false

# Iterate over configurations
while read -r CONFIGURATION; do
    # Get configuration name
    CONFIGURATION_NAME=$(echo $CONFIGURATION | jq -r '.name')
    # Get configuration program
    CONFIGURATION_PROGRAM=$(echo $CONFIGURATION | jq -r '.program')
    # Get configuration args
    CONFIGURATION_ARGS=$(echo $CONFIGURATION | jq -r '.args | join(" ")')
    # Get preLaunchTask if it exists
    PRE_LAUNCH_TASK=$(echo $CONFIGURATION | jq -r '.preLaunchTask // empty')

    # Create run configuration file
    cat <<EOF >$RUN_CONFIGURATIONS_DIR/$CONFIGURATION_NAME.xml
<component name="ProjectRunConfigurationManager">
  <configuration default="false" name="$CONFIGURATION_NAME" type="FlutterRunConfigurationType" factoryName="Flutter">
    <option name="additionalArgs" value="$CONFIGURATION_ARGS" />
    <option name="filePath" value="\$PROJECT_DIR\$/$CONFIGURATION_PROGRAM" />
    <method v="2">
EOF

    # Add Gradle task if preLaunchTask exists
    if [ -n "$PRE_LAUNCH_TASK" ]; then
        HAS_PRE_LAUNCH_TASKS=true
        TASK_COMMAND=$(get_task_command "$PRE_LAUNCH_TASK")
        if [ -n "$TASK_COMMAND" ]; then
            echo "      <option name=\"Gradle.BeforeRunTask\" enabled=\"true\" tasks=\"$CONFIGURATION_NAME\" externalProjectPath=\"\$PROJECT_DIR\$/android/scripts\" vmOptions=\"\" scriptParameters=\"\" />" >>$RUN_CONFIGURATIONS_DIR/$CONFIGURATION_NAME.xml

            # Add task to build.gradle
            cat <<EOF >>$ANDROID_GRADLE_FILE
task $CONFIGURATION_NAME(type: Exec) {
    workingDir "../../"
    commandLine 'bash', '-c', '$TASK_COMMAND'
}

EOF
        fi
    fi

    echo "    </method>" >>$RUN_CONFIGURATIONS_DIR/$CONFIGURATION_NAME.xml
    echo "  </configuration>" >>$RUN_CONFIGURATIONS_DIR/$CONFIGURATION_NAME.xml
    echo "</component>" >>$RUN_CONFIGURATIONS_DIR/$CONFIGURATION_NAME.xml

    # Create script file for running the configuration
    SCRIPT_FILE="$SCRIPTS_DIR/$CONFIGURATION_NAME.sh"
    cat <<EOF >$SCRIPT_FILE
#!/bin/bash

# Usage: ./$CONFIGURATION_NAME.sh [run|build] [additional build args...]
# If no action is provided, it defaults to 'run'
# For 'build', additional arguments can be provided (e.g., ios --no-codesign, aab, etc.)

ACTION=\${1:-run}

# Add preLaunchTask command if it exists
if [ -n "$PRE_LAUNCH_TASK" ]; then
    TASK_COMMAND="$(get_task_command "$PRE_LAUNCH_TASK")"
    if [ -n "\$TASK_COMMAND" ]; then
        \$TASK_COMMAND
    fi
fi

if [ "\$ACTION" = "run" ]; then
    flutter run $CONFIGURATION_ARGS --target=$CONFIGURATION_PROGRAM
elif [ "\$ACTION" = "build" ]; then
    shift 1  # Remove action argument
    flutter build \$@ $CONFIGURATION_ARGS --target=$CONFIGURATION_PROGRAM
else
    echo "Invalid action. Use 'run' or 'build'."
    exit 1
fi
EOF
    chmod +x $SCRIPT_FILE

    echo -e "${SUCCESS}Generated $CONFIGURATION_NAME${RESET}"
done <<<"$CONFIGURATIONS"

# Check if there are any preLaunchTasks
if [ "$HAS_PRE_LAUNCH_TASKS" = false ]; then
    echo "No preLaunchTasks found. Removing $ANDROID_GRADLE_FILE..."
    rm -f $ANDROID_GRADLE_FILE

    # Remove include ":scripts" from settings.gradle if it exists
    if [ -f "$ANDROID_SETTINGS_GRADLE" ]; then
        sed -i '' '/include ":scripts"/d' "$ANDROID_SETTINGS_GRADLE"
        echo "Removed 'include \":scripts\"' from settings.gradle"
        clean_empty_lines "$ANDROID_SETTINGS_GRADLE"
    fi
else
    echo "PreLaunchTasks found. Keeping $ANDROID_GRADLE_FILE..."
    # Update settings.gradle
    if [ -f "$ANDROID_SETTINGS_GRADLE" ]; then
        if ! grep -q "include \":scripts\"" "$ANDROID_SETTINGS_GRADLE"; then
            echo "Updating $ANDROID_SETTINGS_GRADLE..."
            echo "include \":scripts\"" >>"$ANDROID_SETTINGS_GRADLE"
        fi
        clean_empty_lines "$ANDROID_SETTINGS_GRADLE"
    else
        echo -e "${WARN}$ANDROID_SETTINGS_GRADLE not found${RESET}"
    fi
fi

update_makefile

# Check if git is installed, if not, print a warning otherwise add run configurations and scripts to git
if ! command -v git &>/dev/null; then
    echo -e "${WARN}git not found, please install git, or manually add $RUN_CONFIGURATIONS_DIR and $SCRIPTS_DIR to git${RESET}"
else
    echo "Adding run configurations and scripts to git..."
    git add -f $RUN_CONFIGURATIONS_DIR $SCRIPTS_DIR $MAKEFILE
    if [ -f "$ANDROID_GRADLE_FILE" ]; then
        git add -f $ANDROID_GRADLE_FILE
    fi
    if [ -f "$ANDROID_SETTINGS_GRADLE" ]; then
        git add -f $ANDROID_SETTINGS_GRADLE
    fi
fi

# Done
echo -e "${SUCCESS}Done!${RESET}"

exit 0


After some tries I managed to get a build.gradle task which is in fact checked into the vcs :')
What i did was:
Created .idea/runConfigurations/whatever.xml
<component name="ProjectRunConfigurationManager">
  <configuration default="false" name="QA" type="FlutterRunConfigurationType" factoryName="Flutter">
    <option name="additionalArgs" value="--dart-define=X=X --dart-define-from-file=env.json" />
    <option name="filePath" value="$PROJECT_DIR$/lib/main.dart" />
    <method v="2">
      <option name="Gradle.BeforeRunTask" enabled="false" tasks="runCopyScript" externalProjectPath="$PROJECT_DIR$/android/scripts" vmOptions="" scriptParameters="-Penv=qa" />
    </method>
  </configuration>
</component>

So if I wanted to define a variable I'd just use a regular dart define and also a dart-define-from-file just as an example
The important part is inside the ...
I just created another build.gradle under android/scripts/ (Wanted to have it separate from the main build.gradle)
In that script you can do something like:
task runCopyScript(type: Exec) {
    workingDir "../../"

    def scriptFile = './whatever/my_script.sh'
    def environment = project.property('env')

    println "Executing: ${scriptFile} ${environment}"

    commandLine 'bash', scriptFile, "${environment}"
}

And this will run the script with the argument u passed as -Penv (in this case, "qa")
one last thing u would need to do is to modify the /android/settings.gradle` to actually add this sub-folder
just add at the very bottom:
...// previous code i just place it after the [include ":app"] line
include ":scripts"

